# How to put a redirect in front of a php template with a referer check?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-referer, referer

I have a template in my (wordpress) child theme folder for a custom post type that I created. It looks like this:

```
<head>
    …
    <style>
        …
    </style>
    <script>
        …
    </script>
</head>

<header>
    …
</header>

<?php
    …
?>

<div id="content">
    <?php xx_page_header($post->ID); ?>
    …
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is exactly how it is structured. I put it because I am php beginner and if someone is willing to help me, at all, I will most of all need *exact* information *where* exactly to put code snippets (which in the end will look simple and small, I guess).

I have 4 pages that are based on this template page. All of them working well.

Here is what I have to add though:

The pages succeed each other containing input forms etc. and are clicked through by passing the forms, sort of a *filtering* process.

How can I put in front of the template a referer check? So that the pages keep on working their way BUT if someone would copy one of the links and paste it into another browser window he would be redirected always to the **first** page of them instead of seeing the page of the actual link.

I have made some researches as good as I can and found some pieces I would like to use. As is for:

1) the referer part:

```
<?php
    $ref=getenv("HTTP_REFERER");
    $url='url_redirect';
    if($ref!='referer_url'){
       header('Location: '.$url);
    }
?>
```

2) a regex to make it work for all pages that are using the template:

```
ref.match(/^http?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?mywebpage\.com(\/|$)/i)
```

Let’s say the (*filtering*) start page is: www.mywebpage.com/startpage/

How do I have to combine those snippets and where to put it (I guess at the beginning of the template)?

I would like to avoid cookies. (using the referer)

Comment: On your start page are you passing any POST variables?

Comment: Frankly I don’t know. Is it important to know?

Comment: Yes, because you need a variable to check if the variable from start page was set.

Comment: You mean a cookie?

Comment: No. Do each of the 4 pages have their own unique URL? And on start page there is a form?

Comment: Yes. For this I wanted to use the regex (I guess it is called that way) part that I posted under 2) In a way that all of them are covered. On start page is a form, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140215/discussion-between-cosmoonot-and-garavani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could do something similar to the code below. Each of your pages after the start page must have unique urls and a token that is passed along on every page. You need to place this code at the very top of your template.

**Something similar:**

```
<?php    
    $url='url_redirect';
    if((is_page('template2') || is_page('template3') || is_page('template4')) && $_POST['token'] == '') {
       header('Location: '.$url);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I am still struggling with how to do create and pass a token in this concept. I read about wordpress nonces. Are they helpful here? I am using one template for 4 different pages.